# How to setup user policy for the minio bucket using s3Client?

Tags: java, amazon-s3, minio, aws-s3-client, s3-iam-policy

We use Minio as our backend service but we communicate with it through

```
software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3Client
```

I see that this class contains method `putBucketPolicy`

but I don't see any method which allow to assign policy to user. Is there any way to assigh user policy using S3Client ?

Comment: Do you need to assign new policy to your user's role? If it is what you needed, then you can check out IAM SDK (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/iam-examples-policies.html)

Comment: @Abdullah Ilgaz I am looking for a java API. added java tag

Comment: which sdk version are you using?

Comment: version is 2.16.10

Comment: OK. I'll edit my answer to help you about AWS SDK for Java 2.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edited Answer:*

Your updated question helped me determine what you were looking for.

You need to create a policy and assign it to a role. You can then assign that role to your user. The AWS SDK for Java 2.x provides support for all of these actions with IAM.

Here's what we can do:

##### 1- Creating a policy

To create a new policy, provide the policy’s name and a JSON-formatted policy document in a `CreatePolicyRequest` to the **IamClient**’s `createPolicy` method.

**Imports**

```
import software.amazon.awssdk.core.waiters.WaiterResponse;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.iam.model.CreatePolicyRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.iam.model.CreatePolicyResponse;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.iam.model.GetPolicyRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.iam.model.GetPolicyResponse;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.iam.model.IamException;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.iam.IamClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.iam.waiters.IamWaiter;
```

**Code**

```
    public static String createIAMPolicy(IamClient iam, String policyName ) {

        try {
            // Create an IamWaiter object
            IamWaiter iamWaiter = iam.waiter();

            CreatePolicyRequest request = CreatePolicyRequest.builder()
                .policyName(policyName)
                .policyDocument(PolicyDocument).build();

            CreatePolicyResponse response = iam.createPolicy(request);

            // Wait until the policy is created
            GetPolicyRequest polRequest = GetPolicyRequest.builder()
                    .policyArn(response.policy().arn())
                    .build();

            WaiterResponse<GetPolicyResponse> waitUntilPolicyExists = iamWaiter.waitUntilPolicyExists(polRequest);
            waitUntilPolicyExists.matched().response().ifPresent(System.out::println);
            return response.policy().arn();

         } catch (IamException e) {
            System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
        return "" ;
    }
```

*You can check out [CreatePolicy.java](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/javav2/example_code/iam/src/main/java/com/example/iam/CreatePolicy.java) for complete example.*

##### 2- Attach a role policy

You can attach a policy to an IAM role by calling the **IamClient**’s `attachRolePolicy` method.

**Imports**

```
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.iam.IamClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.iam.model.IamException;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.iam.model.AttachRolePolicyRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.iam.model.AttachedPolicy;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.iam.model.ListAttachedRolePoliciesRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.iam.model.ListAttachedRolePoliciesResponse;
import java.util.List;
```

**Code**

```
    public static void attachIAMRolePolicy(IamClient iam, String roleName, String policyArn ) {

        try {

             ListAttachedRolePoliciesRequest request = ListAttachedRolePoliciesRequest.builder()
                    .roleName(roleName)
                    .build();

            ListAttachedRolePoliciesResponse  response = iam.listAttachedRolePolicies(request);
            List<AttachedPolicy> attachedPolicies = response.attachedPolicies();

            // Ensure that the policy is not attached to this role
            String polArn = "";
            for (AttachedPolicy policy: attachedPolicies) {
                polArn = policy.policyArn();
                if (polArn.compareTo(policyArn)==0) {
                   System.out.println(roleName +
                            " policy is already attached to this role.");
                    return;
                }
          }

            AttachRolePolicyRequest attachRequest =
                AttachRolePolicyRequest.builder()
                        .roleName(roleName)
                        .policyArn(policyArn)
                        .build();

            iam.attachRolePolicy(attachRequest);

            System.out.println("Successfully attached policy " + policyArn +
                " to role " + roleName);

         } catch (IamException e) {
                System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
                System.exit(1);
          }

     System.out.println("Done");
    }
```

*You can check out [AttachRolePolicy.java](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/javav2/example_code/iam/src/main/java/com/example/iam/AttachRolePolicy.java) for complete example.*

#### Bonus Content

##### Scenario for create a user and assume a role

The following code example shows how to:

- Create a user who has no permissions.
- Create a role that grants permission to list Amazon S3 buckets for the account.
- Add a policy to let the user assume the role.
- Assume the role and list Amazon S3 buckets using temporary credentials.
- Delete the policy, role, and user.

```
/*
  To run this Java V2 code example, set up your development environment, including your credentials.

  For information, see this documentation topic:

  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html

  This example performs these operations:

  1. Creates a user that has no permissions.
  2. Creates a role and policy that grants Amazon S3 permissions.
  3. Creates a role.
  4. Grants the user permissions.
  5. Gets temporary credentials by assuming the role.  Creates an Amazon S3 Service client object with the temporary credentials.
  6. Deletes the resources.
 */

public class IAMScenario {
    public static final String DASHES = new String(new char[80]).replace("\0", "-");
    public static final String PolicyDocument =
            "{" +
                    "  \"Version\": \"2012-10-17\"," +
                    "  \"Statement\": [" +
                    "    {" +
                    "        \"Effect\": \"Allow\"," +
                    "        \"Action\": [" +
                    "            \"s3:*\"" +
                    "       ]," +
                    "       \"Resource\": \"*\"" +
                    "    }" +
                    "   ]" +
                    "}";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        final String usage = "\n" +
            "Usage:\n" +
            "    <username> <policyName> <roleName> <roleSessionName> <fileLocation> <bucketName> \n\n" +
            "Where:\n" +
            "    username - The name of the IAM user to create. \n\n" +
            "    policyName - The name of the policy to create. \n\n" +
            "    roleName - The name of the role to create. \n\n" +
            "    roleSessionName - The name of the session required for the assumeRole operation. \n\n" +
            "    fileLocation - The file location to the JSON required to create the role (see Readme). \n\n" +
            "    bucketName - The name of the Amazon S3 bucket from which objects are read. \n\n" ;

        if (args.length != 6) {
            System.out.println(usage);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        String userName = args[0];
        String policyName = args[1];
        String roleName = args[2];
        String roleSessionName = args[3];
        String fileLocation = args[4];
        String bucketName = args[5];

        Region region = Region.AWS_GLOBAL;
        IamClient iam = IamClient.builder()
            .region(region)
            .credentialsProvider(ProfileCredentialsProvider.create())
            .build();

        System.out.println(DASHES);
        System.out.println("Welcome to the AWS IAM example scenario.");
        System.out.println(DASHES);

        System.out.println(DASHES);
        System.out.println(" 1. Create the IAM user.");
        Boolean createUser = createIAMUser(iam, userName);
        System.out.println(DASHES);

       if (createUser) {
           System.out.println(userName + " was successfully created.");

           System.out.println(DASHES);
           System.out.println("2. Creates a policy.");
           String polArn = createIAMPolicy(iam, policyName);
           System.out.println("The policy " + polArn + " was successfully created.");
           System.out.println(DASHES);

           System.out.println(DASHES);
           System.out.println("3. Creates a role.");
           String roleArn = createIAMRole(iam, roleName, fileLocation);
           System.out.println(roleArn + " was successfully created.");
           System.out.println(DASHES);

           System.out.println(DASHES);
           System.out.println("4. Grants the user permissions.");
           attachIAMRolePolicy(iam, roleName, polArn);
           System.out.println(DASHES);

           System.out.println(DASHES);
           System.out.println("*** Wait for 1 MIN so the resource is available");
           TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(1);
           System.out.println("5. Gets temporary credentials by assuming the role.");
           System.out.println("Perform an Amazon S3 Service operation using the temporary credentials.");
           assumeGivenRole(roleArn, roleSessionName, bucketName);
           System.out.println(DASHES);

           System.out.println(DASHES);
           System.out.println("6 Getting ready to delete the AWS resources");
           deleteRole(iam, roleName, polArn);
           deleteIAMUser(iam, userName);
           System.out.println(DASHES);

           System.out.println(DASHES);
           System.out.println("This IAM Scenario has successfully completed");
           System.out.println(DASHES);
       } else {
           System.out.println(userName +" was not successfully created.");
       }
    }

    public static Boolean createIAMUser(IamClient iam, String username ) {

        try {
            // Create an IamWaiter object
            IamWaiter iamWaiter = iam.waiter();
            CreateUserRequest request = CreateUserRequest.builder()
                .userName(username)
                .build();

            // Wait until the user is created.
            CreateUserResponse response = iam.createUser(request);
            GetUserRequest userRequest = GetUserRequest.builder()
                .userName(response.user().userName())
                .build();

            WaiterResponse<GetUserResponse> waitUntilUserExists = iamWaiter.waitUntilUserExists(userRequest);
            waitUntilUserExists.matched().response().ifPresent(System.out::println);
            return true;

        } catch (IamException e) {
            System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static String createIAMRole(IamClient iam, String rolename, String fileLocation ) throws Exception {

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) readJsonSimpleDemo(fileLocation);
            CreateRoleRequest request = CreateRoleRequest.builder()
                .roleName(rolename)
                .assumeRolePolicyDocument(jsonObject.toJSONString())
                .description("Created using the AWS SDK for Java")
                .build();

            CreateRoleResponse response = iam.createRole(request);
            System.out.println("The ARN of the role is "+response.role().arn());
            return response.role().arn();

        } catch (IamException e) {
            System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
        return "";
    }

    public static String createIAMPolicy(IamClient iam, String policyName ) {

        try {
            // Create an IamWaiter object.
            IamWaiter iamWaiter = iam.waiter();
            CreatePolicyRequest request = CreatePolicyRequest.builder()
                .policyName(policyName)
                .policyDocument(PolicyDocument).build();

            CreatePolicyResponse response = iam.createPolicy(request);

            // Wait until the policy is created.
            GetPolicyRequest polRequest = GetPolicyRequest.builder()
                .policyArn(response.policy().arn())
                .build();

            WaiterResponse<GetPolicyResponse> waitUntilPolicyExists = iamWaiter.waitUntilPolicyExists(polRequest);
            waitUntilPolicyExists.matched().response().ifPresent(System.out::println);
            return response.policy().arn();

        } catch (IamException e) {
            System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
        return "" ;
    }

    public static void attachIAMRolePolicy(IamClient iam, String roleName, String policyArn ) {

        try {
            ListAttachedRolePoliciesRequest request = ListAttachedRolePoliciesRequest.builder()
                .roleName(roleName)
                .build();

            ListAttachedRolePoliciesResponse response = iam.listAttachedRolePolicies(request);
            List<AttachedPolicy> attachedPolicies = response.attachedPolicies();

            String polArn;
            for (AttachedPolicy policy: attachedPolicies) {
                polArn = policy.policyArn();
                if (polArn.compareTo(policyArn)==0) {
                    System.out.println(roleName + " policy is already attached to this role.");
                    return;
                }
            }

            AttachRolePolicyRequest attachRequest = AttachRolePolicyRequest.builder()
                .roleName(roleName)
                .policyArn(policyArn)
                .build();

            iam.attachRolePolicy(attachRequest);
            System.out.println("Successfully attached policy " + policyArn + " to role " + roleName);

        } catch (IamException e) {
            System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    // Invoke an Amazon S3 operation using the Assumed Role.
    public static void assumeGivenRole(String roleArn, String roleSessionName, String bucketName) {

        StsClient stsClient = StsClient.builder()
            .region(Region.US_EAST_1)
            .build();

        try {
            AssumeRoleRequest roleRequest = AssumeRoleRequest.builder()
                .roleArn(roleArn)
                .roleSessionName(roleSessionName)
                .build();

            AssumeRoleResponse roleResponse = stsClient.assumeRole(roleRequest);
            Credentials myCreds = roleResponse.credentials();
            String key = myCreds.accessKeyId();
            String secKey = myCreds.secretAccessKey();
            String secToken = myCreds.sessionToken();

            // List all objects in an Amazon S3 bucket using the temp creds.
            Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
            S3Client s3 = S3Client.builder()
                .credentialsProvider(StaticCredentialsProvider.create(AwsSessionCredentials.create(key, secKey, secToken)))
                .region(region)
                .build();

            System.out.println("Created a S3Client using temp credentials.");
            System.out.println("Listing objects in "+bucketName);
            ListObjectsRequest listObjects = ListObjectsRequest.builder()
                .bucket(bucketName)
                .build();

            ListObjectsResponse res = s3.listObjects(listObjects);
            List<S3Object> objects = res.contents();
            for (S3Object myValue : objects) {
                System.out.println("The name of the key is " + myValue.key());
                System.out.println("The owner is " + myValue.owner());
            }

        } catch (StsException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    public static void deleteRole(IamClient iam, String roleName, String polArn) {

        try {
            // First the policy needs to be detached.
            DetachRolePolicyRequest rolePolicyRequest = DetachRolePolicyRequest.builder()
                .policyArn(polArn)
                .roleName(roleName)
                .build();

            iam.detachRolePolicy(rolePolicyRequest);

            // Delete the policy.
            DeletePolicyRequest request = DeletePolicyRequest.builder()
                .policyArn(polArn)
                .build();

            iam.deletePolicy(request);
            System.out.println("*** Successfully deleted "+polArn);

            // Delete the role.
            DeleteRoleRequest roleRequest = DeleteRoleRequest.builder()
                .roleName(roleName)
                .build();

            iam.deleteRole(roleRequest);
            System.out.println("*** Successfully deleted " +roleName);

        } catch (IamException e) {
            System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    public static void deleteIAMUser(IamClient iam, String userName) {

        try {
            DeleteUserRequest request = DeleteUserRequest.builder()
                .userName(userName)
                .build();

            iam.deleteUser(request);
            System.out.println("*** Successfully deleted " + userName);

        } catch (IamException e) {
            System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    public static Object readJsonSimpleDemo(String filename) throws Exception {
        FileReader reader = new FileReader(filename);
        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        return jsonParser.parse(reader);
    }
}
```

---

*Original Answer:*

#### PutBucketPolicy

If you don't have `PutBucketPolicy` permissions, Amazon S3 returns a `403 Access Denied` error. If you have the correct permissions, but you're not using an identity that belongs to the bucket owner's account, Amazon S3 returns a `405 Method Not Allowed` error.

You can check out for more from AWS API Reference: [PutBucketPolicy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_PutBucketPolicy.html)

Comment: Soryy maybe my question is clear but its not about usage of PutBucketPolicy. I see that PutBucketPolicy method exists but there are no method for setting up policy to user. I am looking for that method.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work with minio https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74642101/iamexception-invalid-sts-api-version-2010-05-08-expecting-2011-06-15

Comment: It seems like you used "Minio via Aws API". Is that correct?

Comment: you are absolutely correct

Comment: @gstackoverflow AWS SDK and AWS API are totally different approaches. I've never used AWS API.