# IamException: Invalid STS API version 2010-05-08, expecting 2011-06-15

Tags: java, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, minio

I am working with Minio via Aws API and I've encountered the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: software.amazon.awssdk.services.iam.model.IamException: Invalid STS API version 2010-05-08, expecting 2011-06-15 (Service: Iam, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 172CAAE563A5508F, Extended Request ID: null)
    at ***.service.IamService.createIAMPolicy(IamService.java:40) ~[classes/:na]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.web.filter.reactive.ServerWebExchangeContextFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ ***.controller.error.HeaderFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authorization.AuthorizationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authorization.ExceptionTranslationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.logout.LogoutWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.savedrequest.ServerRequestCacheWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.context.SecurityContextServerWebExchangeWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.AuthenticationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.context.ReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.header.HttpHeaderWriterWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity$ServerWebExchangeReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.WebFilterChainProxy [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.reactive.server.MetricsWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ io.opentracing.contrib.spring.web.webfilter.TracingWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ HTTP PUT "/user/qwerty/policy" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Original Stack Trace:
        at ***.IamService.createIAMPolicy(IamService.java:40) ~[classes/:na]
        at ***.UserController.createPolicy(UserController.java:76) ~[classes/:na]
        at ***.UserController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$4149c8a3.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]

        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: software.amazon.awssdk.services.iam.model.IamException: Invalid STS API version 2010-05-08, expecting 2011-06-15 (Service: Iam, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 172CAAE563A5508F, Extended Request ID: null)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:395) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1999) ~[na:na]
    ....
Caused by: software.amazon.awssdk.services.iam.model.IamException: Invalid STS API version 2010-05-08, expecting 2011-06-15 (Service: Iam, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 172CAAE563A5508F, Extended Request ID: null)
```

My code is:

```
   String policyDocument =
        "{" +
                "  \"Version\": \"2012-10-17\"," +
                "  \"Statement\": [" +
                "    {" +
                "        \"Effect\": \"Allow\"," +
                "        \"Action\": [" +
                "            \"s3:DeleteItem\"," +
                "            \"s3:GetItem\"," +
                "            \"s3:PutItem\"," +
                "            \"s3:UpdateItem\"" +
                "       ]," +
                "       \"Resource\": \"*\"" +
                "    }" +
                "   ]" +
                "}";


    IamAsyncClient iam = IamAsyncClient.builder()
            .httpClient(sdkAsyncHttpClient)
            .region(region)
            .credentialsProvider(awsCredentialsProvider)
            .endpointOverride(myProperties.getEndpoint())
            .region(myProperties.getRegion())
            .build();

     CreatePolicyRequest request = CreatePolicyRequest
            .builder()
            .policyName(policyName)
            .policyDocument(policyDocument)
            .build();

    CompletableFuture<CreatePolicyResponse> response= iam.createPolicy(request);
```

I use aws sdk version = `2.18.27`

minio is started using following docker-compose file

```
  minio:
    container_name: minio
    image: bitnami/minio:2022.11.17-debian-11-r0
    volumes:
      - minio-data:/data
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
      - 9001:9001
    environment:
      - MINIO_ROOT_USER=minio
      - MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD=minio123
      - MINIO_DEFAULT_BUCKETS=bucket1,bucket2
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:9000/minio/health/live"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 20s
      retries: 3
```

How to fix it ?

P.S.

I see that this class

https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/iam/transform/CreatePolicyRequestMarshaller.html

contains hardcoded value:

```
private static final OperationInfo SDK_OPERATION_BINDING = OperationInfo.builder().requestUri("/")
        .httpMethod(SdkHttpMethod.POST).hasExplicitPayloadMember(false).hasPayloadMembers(true)
        .operationIdentifier("CreatePolicy").apiVersion("2010-05-08").build();
```

So this value is taken from it. And I don't see a way how to replace it.

Comment: How `policyDocument` look like?

Comment: @YCF_L updated topic. please take a look